# argument type with a private/deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, swig

Let's say I want to typemap `std::type_index` as an argument in SWIG (ignore the utter meaninglessness of said type in the target language).

```
void dosomething(std::type_index arg);
```

Wrapping this function gives the following decldef in generated code, before code generated from typemap methods like `in` and `arginit`:

```
std::type_index arg1;
```

`std::type_index` doesn't have a default constructor. I do not have access to its definition. C++ compilers unceremoniously reject the code.

**How do I get SWIG to generate usable code?**

I've looked at different typemap methods and found nothing; in particular, `typemap(arginit)` looked promising but fell short when it didn't replace the decldef for `arg1`.

**UPDATE:** Changing the function signature to...

```
void dosomething(const std::type_index& arg);
```

... forced SWIG to generate a `std::type_index*` as `arg1`'s type. I'm no less nonplussed that I can't get it to work with pass-by-value, though. My original question stands (in a pool of quadruple negatives).

**EDIT:**

Per request, the manner in which a function calling from Python with a Python string typemapped by SWIG to  `std::type_index` by value would look:

```
dosomething("ClassName")
```

Comment: can you show how you want to call this from target language? what target language type are you mapping from?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant (the erroneous code in question is SWIG's wrapper boilerplate, not the codegen for language bindings), but sure, I put a snippet in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%nodefaultctor` feature:

```
%nodefaultctor std::type_index;  // Disable default constructor generation for that class
```

Since `std::type_index` does not define a default constructor, this should work. Looks like you have to put the statement before you define the class in the .i file so before the `%include` statement for `type_index`.

Detals in section 6.6.2 of SWIG docs (such as http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn8 if you are using SWIG 3 -- but this feature has not changed much since 1.3).

Update: if your goal is to call the function as `dosomething("ClassName")`, then I would look at using `%inline` to create a `dosomething(std::string)` that then calls the `type_index` version. It would look something like this, in your .i file:

```
%include "std_string.i"
%{
%include "dosomething.h"
%}

%inline %{
     void dosomething(std::string arg) 
     {
         ... determine which type index to use ...
         dosomething(type_index(whatever))
     }
%}
```

Comment: This isn't about constructor generation; there's an argument of type `std::type_index` being decldefed in the top-matter of a wrapper of a totally unrelated function. SWIG isn't even generating a wrapper for `std::type_index` to begin with (as should be the case - I don't want it to; I want to typemap to it from something SWIG *does* know about).

Comment: Well if it is a function call parameter then you must export it too otherwise swig will generate cryptic names

Comment: I have no problem with crazy names (I'm assuming 'cryptic' isn't some special keyword here). I'm not using `std::type_index` in the target language. I'm typemapping from a target language entity to a `std::type_index`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that (and the %extend directive)... Still super miffed that SWIG can't just *handle* it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SWIG well, so what I describe here is a general solution. If you really need default constructor, you have to create a wrapper class such as,

```
class TypeIndex {  // C++11
public:
   TypeIndex() { }
   TypeIndex(...): m(new std::type_index(...)) { }
   ~TypeIndex() { delete m; }
   TypeIndex(const TypeIndex &other)
   {
       if (other.m)
           m = new std::type_index(*other.m);
   }
   TypeIndex &operator = (const TypeIndex &rhs) 
   {
       if (!m && !rhs.m)
           return *this;
       if (this != rhs.m) {
           delete m;
           if (!rhs.m)
               m = nullptr;
           else
               m = new std::type_index(*rhs.m);
       }
       return *this;
   }
// and implement wrapping functions as you need, for instance...
   size_t hash_code() const { return m ? m->hash_code() : 0; }
private:
   std::type_index *m = nullptr;
};
```

More simple but potentially dangerous method is to inherit `std::type_index`. In this case, you only need default constructor `TypeIndex() {}`. Note that `std::type_index` does not have virtual destructor, so it won't be safe when polymorphism required.

Comment: This occurred to me, but it feels *wrong*. There *should* be a way to do this in SWIG; it just doesn't seem right for there not to be.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it isn't; that's for generating constructors in the target language, not handling existent/nonexistent constructors in the codegen. Anything specific I missed?

Comment: As I already told you, I'm not familiar with SWIG. I can't understand your situation perfectly. Sorry for that.

Comment: Woah - uhm. Am I coming off as snappy or something? I'm sorry if I am.